# Objective-C Setter Method not working (simple)

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter-setter, nslog

I cannot for the life of me figure out why myRect.origin.x and myRect.origin.y are displaying values of 0. Apologies for the breadth of code, I did remove some things that were clearly not relevant but wasn't so sure on other things. Also, I know that my intersect method doesn't yet work properly but I'm working on it.

```
//Rectangle.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class XYPoint;

@interface Rectangle: GraphicObject

@property float height, width;

-(XYPoint*) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint*) pt;
-(float) area;
-(float) perimeter;
-(void) setHeight: (float) h andWidth: (float) w;
-(void) translate: (XYPoint*) t;
-(BOOL) containspoint: (XYPoint*) aPoint;
-(Rectangle*) intersect: (Rectangle*) intr;

@end

@interface XYPoint: NSObject

@property float x,y;

-(void) setX:(float) xVal andY:(float) yVal;

@end


//Rectangle.m

#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle

{
    XYPoint *origin;
}

@synthesize width, height;

-(float) area
{
    return width*height;
}

-(float) perimeter
{
    return 2*(width*height);
}

-(void) setHeight:(float) h andWidth: (float) w
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt
{
    origin = pt;
}

-(XYPoint*) origin
{
    return origin;
}

-(void) translate:(XYPoint *)t
{
    origin = t;
}

-(BOOL) containspoint:(XYPoint *)aPoint
{
    if (aPoint.x >= self.origin.x && aPoint.x <= self.origin.x + self.width && aPoint.y >= self.origin.y && aPoint.y <= self.origin.y + self.height) {
        return YES;
    }
        else return NO;

}

-(Rectangle*) intersect: (Rectangle*) intr

{

    Rectangle *zerorec = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
    Rectangle *rec1 = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
    Rectangle *rec2 = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

    zerorec.origin.x = 0;
    zerorec.origin.y = 0;
    zerorec.height = 0;
    zerorec.width = 0;

    if ((self.origin.x >= intr.origin.x && self.origin.x <= intr.origin.x + intr.width) || (intr.origin.x >= self.origin.x && intr.origin.x >= self.origin.x + self.width))
    {
        if ((self.origin.y >= intr.origin.y && self.origin.y <= intr.origin.y + intr.height) || (intr.origin.y >= self.origin.y && intr.origin.y >= self.origin.y + self.height))

            NSLog(@"The rectangles intersect");
            //rec 1 = the rectangle with the greater x value

            if (self.origin.x >= intr.origin.x && self.origin.x <= intr.origin.x + intr.width)
                rec1 = self, rec1.origin = self.origin, rec2 = intr, rec2.origin = intr.origin;

            else rec2 = self, rec2.origin = self.origin, rec1 = intr, rec1.origin = intr.origin;



            Rectangle *returnedRec = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

            returnedRec.origin.x = rec1.origin.x;
            returnedRec.origin.y = rec2.origin.y;

            //rec 1  = rectangle with greater y value

            if (self.origin.y > intr.origin.y)
                rec1 = self, rec2 = intr;
            else rec1 = intr, rec2 = self;

            returnedRec.height = rec1.height - (rec1.origin.y - rec2.origin.y);
            returnedRec.width = rec1.width - (rec2.origin.y - rec1.origin.y);

            return returnedRec;
    }



        else return zerorec;

    }

@end


@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX:(float) xVal andY:(float) yVal

{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}

@end

//main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Rectangle *returnedRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

        Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
        Rectangle *yourRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

        [myRect.origin setX:3 andY: 2];
        [myRect setHeight:4 andWidth:5];
        [yourRect.origin setX:6 andY:4];
        [yourRect setHeight:7 andWidth:9];

        myRect.origin.x = 2;
        myRect.origin.y = 3;

        returnedRect = [myRect intersect:yourRect];

        NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f", returnedRect.origin.x, returnedRect.origin.y);

        NSLog(@"height = %f, width = %f", returnedRect.height, returnedRect.width);

        NSLog(@"%f, %f", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I tried using the setX andY method along with setting the x and y values explicitly and the program still returns a value of 0 for the x and y values of myRect.origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your origin is always nil because you never create an object of XYPoint. Add this to your Rectangle class:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the book this problem is from (I missed this part) adds something similar to your answer but in the SetOrigin method implementation itself as we haven't gotten to init as a method yet. What I didn't understand (and what I think I understand now, the following might not be accurate) is that origin being part of the Rectangle class only allocates space for origin but doesn't initialize it and since it's an object itself, it needs to be initialized before it can be used.

Comment: Well not exactly, the memory for your XYPoint gets allocated when you call the alloc method of the class itself. By adding the origin to your Rectangle class your are just adding a pointer to an XYPoint object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never create an instance of `XYPoint` so you're sending a number of messages to `nil`.

You should use `CGRect` (even if your class is a wrapper around it) because it will make your code and life a lot simpler.